# How to install a project using symfony

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I am trying to install on my local machine the following project [connect](https://github.com/dsyph3r/connect) which is using symfony2.
I did perform the following commands:

```
cd myWebDirectory
git clone git://github.com/dsyph3r/connect
git submodule update --init
```

When I try to call the following page from my localhost I get the following error:

```
http://localhost/~myName/connect/web/app_dev.php
Server error
```

If I look to the logs file of apache I read:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): 
Failed opening require
'/Users/myName/Sites/connect/app/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php'
```

How should I install the vendor?
What I did miss?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to install the vendor ("third party") libraries.

```
php bin/vendor install
```

Update: It's a while ago, since I wrote this and it's not valid anymore (for new(er) projects). Since 2.1 it uses [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/)

```
php composer.phar install
```

Comment: If I run the command `php app/console install` from `connect directory` I get the following error: `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/Users/myName/Sites/connect/app/../vendor/symfony/.....`